# Code comments in php : @return tag

Tags: php

I would like to know how to write code comments as per the PEAR standards , for the `@return tag , for the following function in php.

While going through the [PEAR standards](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php), I learnt that:

> 1. Return tags should contain the data type then a description of  the
>    data returned : (*This part is quite clear*)
> 2. Description : By convention, the first noun in the description is the data type of the parameter.  Articles like "a", "an", and  "the"
>    can precede the noun.  The descriptions should start with a phrase.
>    If further description is necessary,follow with sentences.

My question is : How do I write the description for the `@return` tag for the  following function which returns true if the function executes successfully ?

```
function AUTOCODER_writeFile($filename, $code)
{
    $handle = fopen($_POST['db']."/".$filename, "w");  
    fwrite($handle, $code);
    fclose($handle);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is a documentation about "doc commenting": Here the reference to [phpDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html) return statement documentation

Comment: Your function *always* returns true, not just if it's successful...

Comment: `@return bool Always returns true.`

Comment: According to your own link, the *Description* paragraph refers to `@param` not `@return` :-?

Comment: @Alvaro, 
although nothing specific is given for the description for the return tag,there is an example given for return tag which goes something like this :
int the integer of the set mode used. FALSE if foo
     *             could not be set.
The above example is similar to the param tags . In such a case how can i effectively write a description for return tag in my function which always returns true ?

Answer (score 2):

As the page you linked specifies, the **docblock comments** are used to generate the PEAR documentation using [phpDocumentor](https://phpdoc.org).

A minimal docblock comment for your function should look like this:

```
/**
 * @param string $filename
 * @param string $code
 * @return bool
 */
function AUTOCODER_writeFile($filename, $code)
{
    $handle = fopen($_POST['db']."/".$filename, "w");  
    fwrite($handle, $code);
    fclose($handle);
    return true;
}
```

Replace `string` with the correct type for `$code` if it's not a string; it can be only a string or a number (int or float) if your code works this way.

To have a useful docblock describe the purpose of each argument after its name and put a line that describes what the function do. Something like:

```
/**
 * Store a code into a file
 *
 * @param string $filename the name of the file
 * @param string $code     the value to store
 * @return bool
 */
```

You can find more information about how to document your code on the [phpDocumentor's documentation](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html). It is a de-facto standard for PHP documentation; many IDEs understand it and use it to help you with hints and errors detection without running the code.

Comment: axiac, I can now understand the purpose behind writing a useful docblock.
In case of@param , as per the PEAR standards , 
1.By convention, the first noun in the description is the data type of the parameter. Articles like "a", "an", and "the" can precede the noun. 
2.The descriptions should start with a phrase. If further description is necessary,follow with sentences.
Honestly , my knowledge of english grammar is poor . How can i effectively write a description for @param tag in case of the above function?

Comment: In my opinion you can safely ignore PEAR recommendations and just describe the function's reason to exist, the meaning of its arguments (and their possible values when it's appropriate), the possible return values and whatever information you think could help other developers to understand how to use the function and what to expect from it. You, several months from now, are one of these "other developers", too.

Comment: @axiac I agree with that. Leaving apart what relevance PEAR may have in 2016, I find their sample descriptions (*"@param int    $arg2 an integer of how many problems happened"*) annoyingly redundant for no obvious reason.